# Compiling SSIS Projects with Team City

Tags: build, ssis, teamcity

Has anyone done this? If so, what tools/techniques/approaches did you use?

Is it possible to do with installing the SQL Business Studio Version of Visual Studio?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No doubt I'll be proven wrong, but the only bit of code that would  be compiled/built in an SSIS package is the Script task? Is that programmatically available? If not, then I think there's nothing to compile. Do you mean you want to run the package as part of the build process? You could script the execution of the package using the `dtexec` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it folks...

1) Install MSBuild Extensions

2) Created a Build.Xml file as so...

```
<Project ToolsVersion="3.5" DefaultTargets="Default" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\ExtensionPack\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks"/>
<Target Name="Default">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputRoot>../../../build-artifacts</OutputRoot>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <SSISProjectFile Include="SSISProject.dtproj"/>
        <SSISProject Include="@(SSISProjectFile)">
            <OutputDirectory>$(OutputRoot)</OutputDirectory>
        </SSISProject>      
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Namespaces Include="Mynamespace">
            <Prefix>DTS</Prefix>
            <Uri>www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts</Uri>
        </Namespaces>
    </ItemGroup>

    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Xml.XmlFile 
        TaskAction="UpdateElement" 
        File="EnclarityDataImport.dtsx" 
        XPath="//DTS:Property[@DTS:Name='ConfigurationString']" 
        InnerText="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\EnclarityDataImport.dtsConfig"
        Namespaces="@(Namespaces)"/>
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.SqlServer.BuildDeploymentManifest InputProject="@(SSISProject)"/>
</Target>
```

The only trick was the last part of the build here. By default visual studio adds the absolute path to your config and connection string files for your dtsx package. Team City will use these in conjunction with MSBuild extensions to build the package so a local path will break the build because the paths to the build directories in Team City are automatically generated. So using the code above and the $(MSBuildProjectDirectory) you can twiddle the value of the path on your dtsx file so that it points to the path where your compilation is exectuing.

Answer (score 1):

Like booyaa says SSIS projects don't need to be compiled, but what i have done is make the .dtconfigs configurable by the build/deployment process.

I do this so that i can run the packages on deployment in different environments. So the build will copy a template of the dtconfig file.
this contains tokens- `$(Servername)  $(ConnectionString)`
And then i do the replacement on deployment and then execute by wrapping the dtexec in an  command.

Not sure about 2012.