# TeamCity not executing MSBuild command line

Tags: msbuild, ssis, teamcity

I've created a Team City project that will build SSIS v2008 project, utilising MSBuild to create the  SSIS pacakges. I'm able to run to build SSIS project from the command line:

```
      C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3c40e9b3942c4213\Source\ETL.Scheduler\ETL.Schedule
      msbuild Build.xml /t:Default /verbosity:diaG
```

However when I attempt to run from Team City, will fail and state unable to find project file at within the TeamCity build directory.

After following advice given in [Compiling SSIS Projects with Team City](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289725/compiling-ssis-projects-with-team-city), I was able to build SSIS solution in Team City. As stated unable to run from within Team City, but can be done from commandline.

Below is screenshot of the buildstep.

[image]

Can anyone assist with this.

Comment: whats the build log say? click on dropdown next to 'Failed build'

Comment: Step 2/3: Build (MSBuild) (1s)
C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.MsBuildBootstrap.exe /workdir:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3c40e9b3942c4213 /msbuildPath:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\MSBuild.exe
[09:45:43][Step 2/3] in directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3c40e9b3942c4213
[09:45:45][Step 2/3] Failed to start MSBuild.exe. Failed to find project file at path: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3c40e9b3942c4213\Source\ETL.Scheduler\ETL.Scheduler
[09:45:45][Step 2/3] Process exited with code -42

Comment: go to that directory then `:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3c40e9b3942c4213\Source\ETL.Scheduler\ETL.Scheduler` - is your stuff there? if not, then its not being checked out correctly (or at all) in a previous step. you probably have the path wrong if it is being checked out (eg perhaps without `Source\` (just a guess))

Comment: Yes, source directories are created within Team City

Comment: have you actually specified the name of the msbuild file? that looks like a *directory* name, not a filename.

Comment: Updated  and is now: Source/ETL.Scheduler/ETL.Scheduler/Build.xml. States cannot find msbuild extenstions; C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3c40e9b3942c4213\Source\ETL.Scheduler\ETL.Scheduler\Build.xml(2, 9): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\MSBuild\ExtensionPack\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk. Team City runs on .x64 machine.

Comment: yea ok so you are getting somewhere now. that error message is pretty explicit. you need to install `MSBuild.ExtensionPack` on your build server.

Comment: Already installed msbuild extension pack, otherwise when I run team city from the command line will fail when using build xml file.

Comment: google that error youre getting. it doesnt look like it pertains to the installation of msbuild. (rather something else)

Answer (score 3):

The `Build File Path` is relative to the checkout directory.  Try just using `Source\ETL.Scheduler\ETL.....` in that field.

Comment: Done, but made no difference. As stated, workaround is to run msbuild within TeamCity on command line

Comment: From the log it appears that you're not specifying the `Build.xml` at the end of your `Build File Path`.  Could that be it?

Answer (score 1):

After consultation with team city expert and a combination of trial and error, specify directly the build file path - Source/ETL.Scheduler/ETL.Scheduler/Build.xml